# Scala XML does not format apostrohpe

Tags: xml, scala

I haven't found this answer anywhere. Isn't Scala supposed to properly format all special XML characters? Seems it has a problem with the apostrophe. Using 2.10.4.

```
scala> for (s <- List("\"", "'", "&", "<", ">")) println(<root>{s}</root>)
<root>&quot;</root>
<root>'</root>
<root>&amp;</root>
<root>&lt;</root>
<root>&gt;</root>
```

Reference: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Comment: I don't know Scala but the apostroph in XML does not need escaping in element content. Even in attribute content it only needs to be escaped if the attribute value delimiters are apostrophe/single quotes as well: `<foo att="That's fine." att2='That&apos;s fine.'"/>`.

Comment: See also https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax saying "The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section" and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue defining the attribute syntax.

Comment: I think the relevant piece for me is this: To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as " &apos; ", and the double-quote character (") as " &quot; ". But the question is why is quote represented as " &quot; ", but the apostrophe is plain in Scala. Any way you look at it there is some inconsistency here.